# How to dynamically load code in php + database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For some time now I'm thinking about a nice way on how to dynamically load code in php based on database entries. I've tried to look up something related, but couldn't really find anything that answered my question(s) thoroughly. I'm using Laravel - not sure if this might be a subject to solve this particular problem.

See the following code for "example data" where I tried to give a quick overview over the database structure. So for a game, lets say we have characters that can be at a location. Any location basically looks the same. You have a form to write a message at this location - nothing fancy. But then there might be some exceptions. For example you might have a location, that implements some more logic such as listing all online characters (+ showing their current location's name.). Or a location might show some other additional content.

This is what I came up with so far, but neither seems optimal:

- Creating different tables for different types of locations (this seems very bad to me actually).
- Create another table, f.e. `modules`, and have a many-to-many relationship with the location table. the `modules` table would then have entries for a location that tell the application what to "execute". F.e., a location might have the entries `thread`, for allowing to post messages, `list`, for showing an overview of online characters and their locations, `trader`, to allow some gameplay mechanics etc.

To me the second option seems to be kind of the right way of achieving what I want to achieve. I would have classes, functions etc. that would represent these modules. But it too seems very hardcode-y. Meaning, that for one in the code behind I would have to distinct between the values which I might or might not want to change in the future, which then would require a lot of refactoring. Because I have to distinct between strings, this design is prone to typos and what not...

character:

```
id | location_id (nullable) | name
---------------------------------
 1 |                      1 | Test
```

location:

```
id | name
----------------
 1 | Location #1
 2 | Online Characters
```

For the above presented version I would add:

modules:

```
id | name
---------
 1 | thread
 2 | list
 3 | trader
```

location_modules:

```
location_id | modules_id
------------------------
          1 |          1
          1 |          3
          2 |          2
```

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand what you're trying to do but does using polymorphic relations help solve your issue?

Comment: I am not really understand your problem but you can use variables to create objects, like $module = '<string from my database>'; new $module() and so forth.

Comment: @haakym: Hm not sure. It would solve the database design, but then again how would I implement a way to treat certain locations differently than others? From my point of understanding, using only polymorphic relations would require me to create a "type" for every special location.

Comment: Use what you have to define your locations and modules and the linker table. Then use a Factory class to resolve your module identifiers into classes you can execute (http://coderoncode.com/design-patterns/programming/php/coding/development/2014/01/19/design-patterns-php-factories.html)

Comment: @Lee: This solution is very nice and would work perfectly fine if a location would only have 1 module. Since a location can have multiple modules, I would have to create multiple objects for a location. A module would be as simple as calling a method and returning a partial view (or extending a layout by the partial view)... Would you then add a collection of modules to a location that contains the objects? Or what would your take on that be?

Comment: It sounds like you want dynamic partials in your view. So only `@include` a partial if the module is set on that location? So you want to load a location model and stuff that into a Location view and have the partials autoinclude? If thats the case, one solution (there are many) is to create a "module factory view" that switches and includes based on the module. then in your location view, do a foreach loop, include the module factory view and pass in the module to it which will proxy it too the correct partial